# Fill in Missing Dates with Merge in R

Tags: r, date, merge

**df1**: has all dates from 2021-04-20 to 2022-05-15

| Date |
| --- |
| 2021-04-20 |
| 2021-04-21 |
| 2021-04-22 |
| 2021-04-23 |
| 2021-04-24 |
| 2021-04-25 |
| 2021-04-26 |
| ... |
| 2022-04-12 |
| 2022-04-13 |
| 2022-04-14 |
| 2022-05-15 |

**df2:** Random and incomplete list of dates between 2021-04-20 to 2022-05-15

| Date | Group |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-04-20 | 1001 |
| 2021-04-21 | 1001 |
| 2021-04-25 | 1001 |
| 2021-04-27 | 1001 |
| 2021-04-30 | 1001 |
| 2021-05-05 | 1001 |
| 2021-06-06 | 1001 |
| 2021-04-20 | 1002 |
| 2021-04-21 | 1002 |
| 2021-04-22 | 1002 |
| 2021-04-23 | 1002 |
| 2021-05-24 | 1002 |
| 2021-05-22 | 1002 |
| 2021-06-23 | 1002 |
| 2021-06-24 | 1002 |
| 2021-07-01 | 1002 |
| 2021-07-12 | 1002 |
| 2021-08-09 | 1002 |

**dfdesired**: Want to fill in incomplete dates in df2 with dates in df1. I want to do this by group. This means 1001 should start at 2021-04-20 and end at 2022-05-15. 1002 should also start at 2021-04-20 and end at 2022-05-15.

| Date | Group |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-04-20 | 1001 |
| 2021-04-21 | 1001 |
| 2021-04-22 | 1001 |
| 2021-04-23 | 1001 |
| 2021-04-24 | 1001 |
| 2021-04-25 | 1001 |
| 2021-04-26 | 1001 |
| ... | ... |
| 2022-04-12 | 1001 |
| 2022-04-13 | 1001 |
| 2022-04-14 | 1001 |
| 2022-05-15 | 1001 |
| 2021-04-20 | 1002 |
| 2021-04-21 | 1002 |
| 2021-04-22 | 1002 |
| 2021-04-23 | 1002 |
| 2021-04-24 | 1002 |
| 2021-04-25 | 1002 |
| 2021-04-26 | 1002 |
| ... | ... |
| 2022-04-12 | 1002 |
| 2022-04-13 | 1002 |
| 2022-04-14 | 1002 |
| 2022-05-15 | 1002 |

Not sure how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a "blind merge" (cartesian expansion) with `base::merge(..., by=NULL)`. Here, I'm starting with a frame of just unique `Group` values on a new frame of the full date sequence.

```r
dates <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2021-04-20"), as.Date("2022-05-15"), by="day"))
out <- merge(unique(dat[,c("Group"), drop = FALSE]), dates, by = NULL)
head(out)
#   Group       Date
# 1  1001 2021-04-20
# 2  1002 2021-04-20
# 3  1001 2021-04-21
# 4  1002 2021-04-21
# 5  1001 2021-04-22
# 6  1002 2021-04-22
tail(out)
#     Group       Date
# 777  1001 2022-05-13
# 778  1002 2022-05-13
# 779  1001 2022-05-14
# 780  1002 2022-05-14
# 781  1001 2022-05-15
# 782  1002 2022-05-15
```

Data:

```r
dat <- structure(list(Date = c("2021-04-20", "2021-04-21", "2021-04-25", "2021-04-27", "2021-04-30", "2021-05-05", "2021-06-06", "2021-04-20", "2021-04-21", "2021-04-22", "2021-04-23", "2021-05-24", "2021-05-22", "2021-06-23", "2021-06-24", "2021-07-01", "2021-07-12", "2021-08-09"), Group = c(1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

Comment: if df2 in my above example had other variables("New", "Old", "Rejected") that I was also trying to preserve during the merge, how would I do that? Would I use a select statement to keep all of the variables I wanted?

Comment: I'd start with replacing `dat[,c("Group"),drop=FALSE]` with a subset that preserves the columns you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dplyr `solution`:

1. We use `anti_join` to get the `date` that are not in `df2`.
2. then we use `bind_rows` to bind these values to `df2`
3. after getting date format with `ymd` we arrange for `year` and fill `Group` column.
4. some tweaking.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

anti_join(df1, df2) %>% 
  bind_rows(df2) %>% 
  mutate(Date = ymd(Date)) %>% 
  arrange(year(Date)) %>% 
  fill(Group, .direction = "updown") %>% 
  select(1,2) %>% 
  arrange(Group, Date)
```

```
              Date Group
1  2021-04-20  1001
2  2021-04-21  1001
3  2021-04-24  1001
4  2021-04-25  1001
5  2021-04-26  1001
6  2021-04-27  1001
7  2021-04-30  1001
8  2021-05-05  1001
9  2021-06-06  1001
10 2021-04-20  1002
11 2021-04-21  1002
12 2021-04-22  1002
13 2021-04-23  1002
14 2021-05-22  1002
15 2021-05-24  1002
16 2021-06-23  1002
17 2021-06-24  1002
18 2021-07-01  1002
19 2021-07-12  1002
20 2021-08-09  1002
21 2022-04-12  1002
22 2022-04-13  1002
23 2022-04-14  1002
24 2022-05-15  1002
```